# How can I pass some values from gsp to controller in a g:form?

Tags: grails, gsp

I know there are some questions like mine, but I'm hoping to get an explanation of how to do it in Grails.

What I want to do is pass values from a gsp datepicker and textfield to the controller when upon Submit button press.

My thanks in advance

GSP:

```
<g:form action="generateReport">
    <ol>
        <li class="fieldcontain">
            <div class="fieldcontain required">
                <label for="date" style="padding-left: 210px;">
                    <g:message code="Data" default="Data"/>
                    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                    <g:datePicker id="data" name="datapicker" precision="day"></g:datePicker>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fieldcontain">
            <div class="fieldcontain required">
                <label for="date" style="padding-left: 195px;">
                    <g:message code="Time" default="Time"/>
                    <g:textField name="minutes"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <div class="content scaffold-show" style="padding-left: 50px;">
        <g:submitButton value="search" name="button"/>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Controller:

```
def generateReport(){
    log.info("Button pressed")
    redirect(action: "list")        
}
```

Comment: How is yours different from the others ?

Comment: I don't be able to do it... Can you probide me some example with my code, please?

Comment: @D.O. your GSP code was missing the opening `<ol>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer:

the view:

```
<g:textField name="name" />
the controller:
```

Controller:

```
  class SomeController {
      def someAction() {
        def name = params.name
        // do something with name
      }
    }
```